# Mulesoft HTTP request to Salesforce login returns org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream

Tags: salesforce, mule-studio, mule-component

Make a POST HTTP request to Salesforce:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?
```

I am receiving `org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@6ffb2a27`
instead of a Json.

I tried to read using *Object to String*, *Object to Json*, *Byte Array to Object*, but all fails.

**The same request works using Postman. So I believe I am not handling the return in the right way.**

Below the request:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="login.salesforce.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<flow name="sfdc-authenticationFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&amp;client_id=3MVG9dZJodJWITSvw.rnZkDdZh_1cGietbXfzgFJEYnJ8Yjy57qnI8Q4lrlDKuW4TkvmhicgzDypbuoU6IlsJ&amp;client_secret=6092113775661001078&amp;username=rofernando.jaramillo@gmail.com&amp;password=live4everzgWJgEvSxKvXeY82DV0oqdqC" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

Anybody faced the same before?

Comment: What error are you actually having?

Comment: Actually is not a error but I cannot read the message, trying to convert to json the result is : "\u0015\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0002("

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your request and it fails with error `java.io.IOException: Remotely closed`. This means Salesforce closed the connection, probably something in the request is wrong. You have to be sure the HTTP request is nearly similar to the one that works in Postman. To troubleshoot that you can enable [HTTP wire logging](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging) and use the Code feature in Postman to see both HTTP requests.

Note that the HTTP Listener/Requester always returns a type of InputStream that contains the actual value of the payload. You can use DataWeave to parse that.

Comment: Thank @Alejandro Dobniewski, indeed the request were not the same, I was missing Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded .I think this was the issue.